# How to add custom variable in JSON model swift?

Tags: swift, api, networking, model

Please tell me, is it possible to add a new (custom) variable in the model `NewResult`, in which the data come from the API? I want to add the `isFavorite: Bool` variable to the model in order to track changes and swap this variable in the future.

Here is my model:

```
class News: Codable {
    var results: [NewResult]?
}


class NewResult: Codable {
    var isFavorite = false
    let url: String?
    let section: String?
    let byline: String?
    let title, abstract, publishedDate: String?
    let media: [Media]?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case url
    case section
    case byline
    case title
    case abstract
    case publishedDate = "published_date"
    case media
  }
}

class Media: Codable {
    let mediaMetadata: [MediaMetadata]?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case mediaMetadata = "media-metadata"
  }
}


class MediaMetadata: Codable {
    let url: String?

}
```

I use Alamofire, so that is my method for requestData:

```
static func requestData(url: String, completion: @escaping (News) -> ()) {

    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

    request(url).responseData { (responseData) in

        switch responseData.result {

        case .success(let data):

            guard let news = try? JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: data) else { return }

            completion(news)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

In my `MainVC` class I have standard methods of `TableViewDelegate`,`TableViewDataSource`, and `Navigation` to `Detail VC`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }

    guard let destination = segue.destination as? DetailViewController else { return }
    destination.currentNew = news?.results?[indexPath.row]
}
```

In `DetailVC` I have `webView`:

```
// MARK: - Properties

var currentNew: NewResult!
private var isFavorite = false

// MARK: - @IBOutlets

@IBOutlet var progressView: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet var favoriteButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let newUrl = currentNew.url

    guard let url = URL(string: newURL) else { return }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    webView.load(request)
  }

 // MARK: - @IBAction

@IBAction func addToFavorite(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    self.isFavorite.toggle()

    self.currentNew.isFavorite = self.isFavorite

    setFavoriteButton(isFavorite: self.isFavorite)

  }

 // MARK: - Methods

private func setFavoriteButton(isFavorite: Bool) {

    if isFavorite {
        favoriteButton.image = UIImage(named: "favoriteTrue")
        // and here I should change variable isFavorite in currentNew and in news
    } else {
        favoriteButton.image = UIImage(named: "favoriteFalse")
        // and also here
    }
}
}
```

And when I return to `MainVC` and select `results[indexPath.row]` that is already in my favorites, the `results` should be with the changes even after the application is restarted.

Comment: What do you mean by "a new custom variable"? A variable that is not provided by the API?

Comment: @rraphael Yes it is! I want to make the button "Add to Favorites", when it is enabled, the variable `isFavorite = true` and added to the database and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a property `isFavourite` in `NewResult`, i.e.

```
struct NewResult: Codable {
    //all other properties....
    var isFavorite = false

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        //don't include isFavorite here...
        //all the other cases...
    }
}
```

Don't include the `case` for `isFavourite` in `enum CodingKeys`.

**Usage:**

Since you want to modify `results` later, so change it from `let` to `var`, i.e

```
struct News: Codable {
    var results: [NewResult]?
}
```

Now, parsing the JSON and modify the `results` with `isFavourite = true`

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        var news = try JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: data)
        news.results = news.results?.map({
            var tempResult = $0
            tempResult.isFavourite = true
            return tempResult
        })
        print(news)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In **`DetailVC`**, you must have a property of type `NewResult`. When the `starButton` is *selected/deselected*, update the `isFavourite` value of the `result` based on it, i.e.

```
class DetailVC: UIViewController {
    var result: NewResult?

    func onTapStarButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        self.result?.isFavourite = sender.isSelected
    }
}
```

**Note:** Make your models `class` instead of `struct` in case to want to track the changes across multiple screens.

Comment: When I do according to your advice and changed `isFavorite = true`, my `arrayOfJSONNewResults[indexPath.row]` is still false `isFavorite = false`

Comment: What is `arrayOfJSONNewResults`?

Comment: I mean `results: [NewResult]` Change is not saved

Comment: It's work! But now all `results` are `true`. And I want to choose between them myself, what will be the `isFavorite`

Comment: You can write your own logic of `isFavourite` where I've used `tempResult.isFavourite = true`. Since it wasn't mentioned in the question, that's why I used `isFavourite=true` for all the values in `results `.

Comment: How I can fixed this problem? Can you help me?

Comment: Ya sure. For that you need to tell me the logic that you want to use to update `isFavourite`. Like based on what condition you want to set `isFavourite` as `true/false`?

Comment: I have 2 `TableViewContoller`. `MainVC` and `DetailVC` In `DetailVC` I have a button, from two pictures (empty star / full star) that should switch the state of `isFavorite`, so that when I switch back this change to` results [indexPath.row] `will be saved in the model. And if in `MainVC` I click on the another result and it's `isFavorite = false`, button will set empty star. Exactly in `MainVC` I have method `requestData`

Comment: I've updated the answer. So add the code for `MainVC` and 'DetailVC` to the question.

Comment: when I reloaded my app changes didn't save

Comment: I'll be able to guide you more if you add the relevant code. Also, you must create a separate thread for this with all the details so others can help too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your variable with a default value in your `Decodable` struct, and omit it in the `CodingKey` list

```swift
var json = """
{"id": 0, "description": "Hello world"}
"""

struct User: Decodable {
    var identifier: Int
    var description: String
    var isFavorite = false

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case identifier = "id"
        case description
    }
}

let user = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```